# freezing animation/preventing callback animation of hover out from playing

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, animation, callback, hover

I know there are a few similar questions out there, but I'm trying their solutions and it's not working for me.

How can I stop the callback animation below, once `#hitbox` is clicked? In the animation, when `#hitbox` is hovered over the divs will move outwards, and when the mouse leaves `#hitbox` the divs will move back into their original positions. I want the divs to stay in their outward positions after `#hitbox` is clicked, instead of moving back in.

```
var timeOut;
$('#hitbox').hover(
            function() {  
                 clearTimeout(timeOut);

    // **some animation functions moving divs outward** e.g.:
    $('#div').stop().animate(
    {
   'margin-left': '-500px',   
    }, 1000, 'easeOutQuart'  
    ); 

                     } // End first function

    ,

            function() {
                timeOut=setTimeout(function(){

    // **some animation functions moving divs back in** e.g.:
    $('#div').animate(
    {  
    'margin-left':'0px',
    }, 900, 'easeOutExpo'  );

                }, 600); //end setTimeout

            } //end second callback function
); //end hover

$('#hitbox').click(function() {
    $('#hitbox').css(
             {'display': 'none',
             });

clearTimeout(timeOut);  // *****NOT WORKING*****


}); // end click
```

Once `#hitbox` is clicked, the divs will move upwards, but they will contract (move back inwards) when I want them to stay in exactly their outward positions.

`clearTimeout(timeOut);` 
is not working as suggested in some other questions. I have a feeling I need a bit more than that? As you can see in the code, I also tried setting the display of `#hitbox` immediately to `none`.
Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a `clicked` class to `#hitbox`, which can be used to check if the contents of the `mouseleave` handler should be executed:

```
$('#hitbox').click(function() {
    $(this).css({
        'display': 'none',
    });
    $(this).addClass('clicked');
});
```

Your second handler for the `hover` method would look like this:

```
function() {

    if($(this).is(":not(.clicked)")){
        timeOut=setTimeout(function(){  // setTimeout method retained instead of using delay() 
        // **some animation functions moving divs back in** e.g.:
        $('#div')/*.delay(600)*/.animate({ // delay removed due to issues w/ animation queue buildup
            'margin-left': '0px',
        }, 900, 'easeOutExpo');

       }, 600); //end setTimeout
    } // end  if()

} // end hover
```

Comment: in my second handler for the hover method, where would I place "timeOut=setTimeout(function(){" ?

Comment: @ShaltNot You should abandon the timeout altogether, since you don't really need it. If you want to delay the action, just add `.delay(600)` to your method chain. I've added this to the answer.

Comment: Ah. I also just tried adding timeOut before the the if() function, and it worked! I'll test out the delay() too. Thank you!! This question received no answers previously.

Comment: Unfortunately, the delay() was not a suitable method because it recreated issues with animation queue buildup, which I was using clearTimeOut to resolve. placing timeOut before the if() seemed to work without flaws though. I've edited your answer to reflect this. Feel free to re-revise! Thanks again!!

Answer (score 1):

While I like @Asad's answer, it looks like `#hitbox` disappears when you click it, so maybe you truly just want to unbind the hover (`mouseleave`) event? If so, just replace this:

```
clearTimeout(timeOut);  // *****NOT WORKING*****
```

with this:

```
$('#hitbox').unbind('mouseleave');
```

**EDIT:**

[Here's a jsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/QrGr2/)

(To make this quick-and-dirty demo work, I added squares, added your code inside the `ready` handler, removed the `easeOut` parameters, and changed the direction of animation.)

Comment: I thought of this, but it is expensive because instead of just adding/removing a class you need to deregister/register the event handler.

Comment: This worked too! I'm not experienced enough to say whether it's a better method, but thank you! Clever trick to make use of display: none...

Comment: @Asad - I see. (I'm not familiar with the internals, so I take your word for it.) Another argument is, if we ever wanted to restore `#hitbox` at some point, we'd have to re-register the event, so your answer would be clearly superior.